# How can I build a 6D Convolution Layer in a CNN, using R or Python?

Tags: r, python, conv-neural-network, spatial, convolution

As stated in the title, I would like to build an N-dimensional Convolutional Layer as part of a Convolution Neural Network, without doing dimensionality reduction on my data; because I have multiple spatial features. I am a bit stumped as to what the best package to build one would be, or where to start. It looks like both Pytorch and Tensorflow lack the ability to create this type of high dimensional convolution layer.

E.g. Imagine I have 6 spatial dimensions, and I want to input them to a 6-dimensional CNN layer.

To be clear, I'm dealing with high-dimensional but manageable counts, and I am okay with relatively long training times. This is mostly an exercise in curiosity, at the moment.

EDIT: To be more precise, what I have is 3D vectors in a relatively sparse 6D space with short dimensions. I definitely want to use a true 6D convolution in the first layer. That is the specific aim of this exercise. I am just looking for the mechanics of how to achieve this. It seems Nvidia/MinkowskiEngine on GitHub might address my dilemma.
https://github.com/NVIDIA/MinkowskiEngine

Comment: Why would you want to convolve along a translation-rotation space? When people say N-dimensional convolution, they mean that the convolutional filter is N-dimensional. How is your data organized? Also, be sure this isn't a [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: @Firebug I am looking to predict the chaotic motion of bodies in a 3D space using both translation and rotation vectors. Think bouncy balls. Rotation vectors are grouped into a relatively small number of discrete buckets, just like translation vectors. 

As I said, this is a curiosity. I want to see how such a model might compare with predicting the motion of bouncing balls, vs using a 3D CNN with translation vectors only.

Comment: So your convolution is actually along time, it's a 1D convolution with 6 input channels

Comment: Could you make an example of the convolution that you want to perform by writing it down as a mathematical formula. You have a 6D image that you want to integrate over?

Comment: @Firebug In actual fact what I described is not my use case (it was just an interesting toy problem that I thought captured the essence of what I am aiming to do). I am sorry for misleading you. I am unable to describe it because of confidentiality reasons. I have 6 dimensional data, where the dimensions are very small. As I said, this is a curiosity I would like to test out, so I very much am looking to specifically test out a 6D CNN layer, and to contrast the performance of a model built with that against other approaches I am using.

Comment: "where the dimensions are very small" what is the size of the entire space and the size of the kernel that you are looking for?

Comment: *"what I have is 3D vectors in a relatively sparse 6D space"* So your data has a 6D shape but it is not like a 6D space where every coordinate has a value? How are you gonna perform a convolution with that, you assume that all the other coordinates are zero? But in that case your output is gonna be the full 6D space. The input might be sparse but the output is not.

Comment: You might perform two 3D convolutions one after the other. For the 3D convolution in the sparse space you probably would like to use a sparse convolution. For Pytorch somebody has already written the code to do this ([SparseConvNet](https://github.com/btgraham/SparseConvNet)). In keras you might [define a layer yourself](https://keras.io/guides/making_new_layers_and_models_via_subclassing/).

Comment: If the data is very sparse, a few $n$ vectors in 6D space, then maybe you could compute all the $n(n-1)/2$ difference vectors and use those as input for the neural network.

Comment: @SextusEmpiricue It is a 6D space where every dimension has a value. But the vectors in it are 3D vectors which are orthogonal in 6D (technically they're 6D, but have 0s in the other 3 dimensions). I do desire a 6D output, in an even smaller space. Most of the vectors are simply boolean. One of the vectors is longer. Each vector will have combinations of 2 boolean axes, and the longer vector. Encoding those to a less sparse 6D matrix is okay. I actually have some ideas for adding vectors in more than 3D dimensions to it as well, but I am leaving that as an exercise for after this one.

Comment: I fully acknowledge that what I am doing is weird. This is driven by curiosity.

Comment: @David you say, 'every dimension has a value', but with my question "like a 6D space where every coordinate has a value? " I meant every coordinate in the *entire* 6D space. For instance if your dimensions have a length of 100 coordinate points, then you end up with 100^6 = 10^12 different coordinate points.

Comment: Convolutions are computed at every point in the space.

Comment: "Most of the vectors are simply boolean" Do you mean that you only have values 0 and 1? How are you gonna perform a convolution if there are only 2 discrete values?

Comment: Because the kernel will cover the [edit: binary] columns, and a segment of the one longer vector. The idea is that I want it to encode information about both the other long vector, and the binary dimensions they exist in. The window will only slide along the axis of the longer vector, since the short vectors will always be inside the kernel window.

Comment: I'm comparing this to a more traditional approach with one-hot encoding.

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus The other orthogonal long vector segments will also be included in the kernel for the convolutions, so another combination of binary dimensions effectively just encodes another vector. This is especially relevant for vectors that share 1 boolean dimension. I also have some ideas about interpolation or combinations I could do to make the space less sparse (e.g. 3 boolean values with a long vector), but I would have to model the data using another approach to achieve that. Hence why I'm focusing on this sparser example as a proof of concept.

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus If my long vector is length 15 (still pretty short), and my short vectors are 2 (I also have a variant I'm going to try with length 3, but ignore that for now), that gives 480 points. Far smaller than most 2D images. Hence why I'm not concerned about performance.

Comment: You don't have to describe your data, but it would be much easier if you described the input "tensor" (aka multidimensional array), in terms of spacetime-like dimensions and non-spacetime-like dimensions. Convolutions are usually performed along spacetime-like dimensions (e.g. Euclidean coordinates, time) over the rest of the variables. Then describe what the output should look like.

Answer (score 2):

#### Time series of a coordinate in 6D space

It might be that one has 6+1D coordinates for time and space but one only wants to convolve along the time direction.

For instance, if derivatives are important, then your code will learn to compute convolutions like
$$\begin{array}{llllllllll}
x^\prime_t& \approx &  +1 x_t &-1 x_{t-1}\\
x^{\prime\prime}_t 
&\approx& +1 x_t &- 2 x_{t-1} &+1x_{t-2}\end{array}$$ and you could get more precise coefficients that resemble some Savitky-Golay filter.

You could also perform a multidimensional convolution, those type of filters have multidimensional equivalents, but if you do not have a 6D image (all points in the 6D space have a value), and instead only a (time-)curve of coordinates inside that space, then using 1D convolutions seems better (much less computations).

#### The case of a multidimensional kernel, but only integration steps in a few directions.

In the comments a case is described of a 6D discrete space where the some axes have only Boolean or few values.

In that case one can reshape the space and perform the convolution with a stride.

Example in 2x6 cases convolved with a 2x2 kernel

$$\text{input$_{2\times6}$} = \begin{bmatrix}{}
x_{11}&x_{12}&x_{13}&x_{14}&x_{15}&x_{16}\\
x_{21}&x_{22}&x_{23}&x_{24}&x_{25}&x_{16}\\
\end{bmatrix}$$

If you properly reshape this then you get

$$\text{reshaped input$_{1\times12}$} = \vphantom{\begin{bmatrix}\rlap{{\overbrace{\phantom{x_{11}\,x_{21}\,x_{12}\,x_{22}}}^{\substack{\text{first step operates}\\\text{on these four}}}}}x_{11}\, x_{21}{\underbrace{x_{12}\,x_{22}\,x_{13}\,x_{23}}_{\substack{\text{second step operates}\\\text{on these four}}}}\,x_{14}\,x_{24}\,x_{15}\,x_{25}\,x_{16}\,x_{26}\end{bmatrix}}
\begin{bmatrix}\rlap{\smash{\overbrace{\phantom{x_{11}\,x_{21}\,x_{12}\,x_{22}}}^{\substack{\text{first step operates}\\\text{on these four}}}}}x_{11}\, x_{21}\smash{\underbrace{x_{12}\,x_{22}\,x_{13}\,x_{23}}_{\substack{\text{second step operates}\\\text{on these four}}}}\,x_{14}\,x_{24}\,x_{15}\,x_{25}\,x_{16}\,x_{26}\end{bmatrix}$$

And your convolution will have a kernel size of 1x4 and a stride of 2. In the above expression I have shown this for the first two steps of the convolution, and eventually the output will be of size $6-1 = 5$.

Alternatively, you convolve over your desired subset of $n$ dimensions and treat the other $6-n$ dimensions as defining different channels (such that the kernel differ per channel), then afterwards you apply a layer that adds the channels together (effectively ending up with a convolution along $n$ dimensions with a 6D kernel).

More generally if you have a space of shape/size $x_1 \times x_2 \times x_3 \times x_4 \times x_5 \times x_6$ and you convolve with a kernel of shape/size $k_1 \times k_2 \times k_3 \times k_4 \times k_5 \times k_6$ then you end up with dimensions of size $y_i = x_i - (k_i-1)$. If also some of the kernel dimensions have the same length as the input shape the (ie if $x_i = k_i$), then you will end up with output shape that has dimensions of length one $y_i = 1$. If you have an output shape with more than 3 of the 6 dimensions of length one, then you can use one of the lower dimensional convolution layers.

In the example, the $2 \times 6$ shape is effectively a 1D convolution with an output shape of $1 \times 5$.

Comment: A 2D kernel will absolutely lose spatial information. If I line those long vectors up tail on tail, the relevant spatial information I am trying to capture will be lost (although it is still an open question as to how helpful the spatial information would be to the model - that remains to be tested). I appreciate your follow-ups, but as I stated earlier I'm really looking for how to go about creating a 6D kernel which maps the 6D data to a 6D layer, then I'll process subsequent layers down into fewer dimensions. It is this step I am a bit stuck on, and seeking assistance for.

Comment: @David the 2D kernel is just an example. You will do it of course in 6D. With the example I show a convolution in a 2D space that occurs only along a single direction. This is what you indicated is also your situation. You have a 6D space but the convolution only happens along a few dimensions. This means that the output is not 6D....

Comment: ...The coordinates have for several dimensions (certainly the dichotomic ones) only one value (and effectively the dimension doesn't play a role) because the kernel takes up the entire space along certain dimensions. In the example we convolve a 2D space of size $k \times l$ with a kernel of size $2 \times 2$, and we end up with an output size of $k-1 \times l-1$. More specifically the input is $2 \times 6$ and we end with output of size $1 \times 5$, reducing the dimension effectively by one.

Comment: *"A 2D kernel will absolutely lose spatial information."* I am not saying that you should use a 2D kernel. I use a 2D kernel as *example* to demonstrate the lowering of the dimensions to perform a convolution with a 2D kernel in a 1D convolution. In your case the situation will be with a 6D kernel. The idea is that the dimension of the kernel is not limited to 2 or 3 when you use the 2d or 3d convolution layers. It can be as many dimensions as you want, it is however the directions of the convolution that are limited.